# How do we show that gluon-fields have color?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, quantum-chromodynamics, strong-force, gluons, color-charge

I understand how to derive the QCD lagrangian based on certain assumptions about Quark fields and $SU(3)$ gauge invariance and in the final expression one finds the term $(A_µ)^c*T_c$ where $T_c$ is one half the gell-mann matrices, and $(A_µ)^c$ is the c-th gluon field, with $µ$ as a spacetime index.

I can clearly see there is gluon 3 and gluon 4-vertex terms in the lagrangian, so these fields certainly are self interacting, is this enough to declare they must have 'color'? This is the leap I'm having trouble with.

I know these must be computed in the adjoint representation of $SU(3)$, but how does one show that these fields must also have the quantum number color?

Comment: Why not just point out the existence of the 3-gluon and 4-gluon vertices in the QCD Lagrangian?

Comment: @probably_someone you're right I should make this question slightly more nuanced

Comment: What space do you gather the SU(3) matrices act on?

Comment: @Hugo V, I added your edits, after accidentally overwriting them

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos this is a great comment I had not thought of at all. Can you add any more insight?

Comment: SU(3) is represented by *color* group matrices *T* which scramble components of abstract *color* vectors, of dimension 3 for quarks and 8 for gluons. I fear the text you learned about them in has already explained this better.

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos it all makes sense now! Thank you for helping me realize that *how* I was thinking was mistaken :)